# How to formulate a maximum size k-plex problem in integer linear programming?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

First, k-plex is a subgraph that each vertex is connected to at least n-k vertices, where n is the size of subgraph.

I found some materials that similar to k-plex : page 5 of
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.4074&rep=rep1&type=pdf

This gave a formulation of k-clique(each vertex is connected to other vertices).

But I still don't know how to formulate a k-plex.

How to formulate a maximum size k-plex problem in integer linear programming?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_v$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and only if vertex $v\in V$ is selected. 
$$
\mbox{Max } n
$$
subject to:

1. Define $n$ : $$n=\sum_{u\in V}x_u$$
2. If vertex $v$ is selected, it must have at least $n-k$ neighbours : $$\deg(v)\ge n-k - M(1-x_v)\quad \forall v \in V$$
3. Variables are binary : $$x_v \in \{0,1\}$$

$M$ is a large constant, e.g., $M:=|V|$. This way, if $x_v=1$, you have the constraint $\deg(v)\ge n-k$ (i.e., $v$ must have at least $n-k$ neighbours), otherwise the constraint is no longer active.

---

EDIT :

If the $n-k$ vertices have to be part of the $k$-plex, then replace the second constraint by 
$$
\sum_{u\in N_v} x_u\ge n-k - M(1-x_v)\quad \forall v \in V
$$
Where $N_v$ denotes the set of vertices adjacent to $v$.

Comment: I would have thought that if this generalizes maximum clique, then every vertex should be adjacent to at least $n-k$ vertices within the selected subgraph?

Comment: I am confused about deg(v), how can I know a vertex's degree from the formulation? Or it will be known after the selection of vertices?

Comment: No, $deg(v)$ is known in advance, it is independent of the selected vertices. Maybe I misunderstood the problem ? Do the $n-k$ vertices have to be part of the $k$-plex as suggested by Michal Adamaszek?

Comment: If so I have edited accordingly.